# Form Redirecting to Homepage

Tags: templating

I'm trying to make a form redirect to the current page, but it's currently redirecting itself to the homepage every time the form submits? I can't see anything wrong with the code itself?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.url }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
  <textarea id="summernote" name="fields[userAbout]">{{ currentUser.userAbout }}</textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md semi-bold mt-4" type="submit">Save Profile</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Little hint: if you remove the `redirect` at all it should always remain on the same page and doesn't redirect to another one unless you have certain events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its because you are not "hashing" the URL. Either use this https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#redirectinput-url or as that the link also mentions:

```twig
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.app.request.absoluteUrl|hash }}">
```